# Кавычки в названиях железнодорожных станций

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, названия

Нужны ли? При этом следует принимать во внимание тот факт, что станция может называться "Москва", а может - "платформа 47й километр". Если кавычки нужны, то как будет выглядеть информационное сообщение с перечислением, например, станций отправления и станций прибытия?
А нужны ли кавычки в названиях станций метро? Аэропортов?

Comment: Мне самой кажется, что не нужны. Просто исходя из соображений здравого смысла: как правило, название станции совпадает с названием местности, коорое мы в кавычки не берем. В справочной литературе можно найти оба варианта. Тогда - опять ж из соображений здравого смысла - я бы выбрала варинат "без кавычек". Но не все со мной согласны!

Answer (score 1):

Нет, географические названия в кавычки не берутся вообще. Например, *аэропорт Пулково, станция Кольчугино*.
Подробнее об этом [вот здесь](http://library.rusbiz.ru/article_index.html?cat=6&id=5487)